# Faster way to concatenate two series in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, series

I have to string type series columns in a pandas data frame and want to concatenate the two of them separated by a ", " to get a result like 'A1, B1'.  How can I do this in a quick way without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

make sure column A and B are both string type and then use

```
df.A + "," + df.B
```

Comment: Or even better. don't pre-"make sure" and do: `df.A.astype(str) + "," + df.B.astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax: Series.str.cat(others=None, sep=None, na_rep=None)**

```
new = data["B1"].copy()

data["A1"]= data["A1"].str.cat(new, sep =", ")
```

source:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-cat-to-concatenate-string/

or using dataframe

```
df["A1"]=df["A1"]+","+df["B1"]
```